# automatically prepend variable in for loop without having to put variable on each line

Tags: bash, script

Is there a way to automatically have the $i variable prepended to the beginning of the command without having to specify it each time?

Here is my current script.

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in "command -c"; do

$i command1 show

$i command2 show

done
```

What I would like is something like this.

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in "command -c"; do
$i
(
command1 show

command2 show
)
done
```

Comment: That script does not make sense, try `for i in "command -c"; do echo $i; done`. I think you mean `for i in $(command -c)` but in any case, scripting questions are not really on topic here. Why don't you ask this on [unix.se] instead?

Comment: The answer is "no" in general, unless whatever is in $i allows it.

Comment: Your question would make more sense if it weren't abusing the Bourne Again shell's built-in `commmand` command with nonsense options.